# Facebook like button: All pages show either '0 likes' or '{total number} likes'

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I'm getting some strange results with the Facebook like button (strange to me anyway) I have the like button on several pages of my site, but the number of likes displayed on each button is always the same - 0 if the page hasn't been like and if the page has been like it displayed the total number of likes for the site itself.

On the users dashboard I allow them to 'like' my Facebook page, here's the iframe I use:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?
href=http://www.facebook.com/myfacebookpage&amp;send=false&amp;
layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;
colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;appId={MY ID HERE}"
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px;
height:20px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Then on users' profile pages I allow visitors to like each profile page.

For the page http://mywebsite.com/john:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?
href=http%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%2Fjohn&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count
&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;
font&amp;height=21&amp;appId={MY ID HERE}" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:20px;"
allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

For the page http://mywebsite.com/billy:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?
href=http%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%2Fbilly&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;
width=100&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;
height=21&amp;appId={MY ID HERE}" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none;
overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:20px;"` allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

As you can see I'm passing different href values for each, so as far as I can see (and read in the docs) I'm doing it correctly... Been researching this for hours with no joy. Anyone ever come across similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer!

In the open graph meta-data og:url is always set to http://mysite.com

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Answer (score 0):

The "like plugin" is not really used for Facebook pages.   You will want to use the "like box plugin" when dealing with pages.  It has many more features than the like plugin does.  Check it out:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/